# How to implement mouse_event() to work continuously in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, mouseevent, myo

I am trying to make a MFC Program using Myo.

I made several combo box control for each gesture.

This is my plan.

---

When I select an option of combo box, It should work as a real mouse.

(e.g. : If I choose option(Left Click), 
it should allow me to do Left click when I take a pose "Fist" && Myo is in unlock state.

```
void CMyoControllerView::OnCbnSelchangeComboFist() {
   int nIndex = m_combo_Fist.GetCurSel();

   if(nIndex == 0) {// Left Click
     if(collector.isUnlocked == true && collector.currentPose == myo::Pose::fist) { 
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
      }
   }
}
```

However, this code only affects mouse just when I change the option(ONLY ONE TIME!).

I know that I should not put this code in control event code.
The problem is that I have no idea where should I put it.

I want to make this function working continuously until I finish this program.

(Like a thread.. I have five combo box and each has different mouse event. All five function should be working together.)

Please give me some advices.
Thank you.

Comment: [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) is all the rage.

Answer (score 0):

Create a queue of actions.  Have the combobox handler put a click action into the queue.  Use a separate timer or thread to process actions that are in the queue.  If an action needs to be repeated, put it back in the queue after it has finished.