# How to make mouse function run continuously in the background?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

Few days ago, I asked a question and got answer.
However I could not proceed any more because of some problems.
(=> [How to implement mouse_event() to work continuously in MFC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449209/how-to-implement-mouse-event-to-work-continuously-in-mfc))

(I am trying to make a MFC program which works like a mouse by using Myo.)

First, I made a Thread Function.

```
UINT CMyoControllerView::ThreadFunc(LPVOID pParam) {   
int index= (int)pParam; 

while(1) {
    if(index == 0) {        // Left Click
        //if Myo is in unlock state & Pose is Fist
        if(collector.isUnlocked == true && collector.currentPose == myo::Pose::fist) {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
        }
    }
    else if(index == 1) {   //Double click
        if(collector.isUnlocked == true && collector.currentPose == myo::Pose::fist) {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, NULL); 
        }
    }
    else if(index == 2) {       // Right Click
        if(collector.isUnlocked == true && collector.currentPose == myo::Pose::fist) {  
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
        }
    }
    else if(index == 3) {       // Wheel Click
        if(collector.isUnlocked == true && collector.currentPose == myo::Pose::fist) {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN, 0, 0, 0, NULL); 
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
        }
    }
    else if(index == 4) {       // Wheel Scroll
        if(collector.isUnlocked == true && collector.currentPose == myo::Pose::fist) {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
        }
    }
    else { 
        continue;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

And this is a message which is produced when I select an option in Combo box.

```
void CMyoControllerView::OnCbnSelchangeComboFist()
{
int nIndex = m_combo_Fist.GetCurSel(); 

CString str; 

if(nIndex != CB_ERR){ 
    m_combo_Fist.GetLBText(nIndex, str); 

    if(str == "Left Click") {
        INDEX = 0;
    } else if(str == "Double Click") {
        INDEX = 1;
    } else if(str == "Right Click") {
        INDEX = 2;
    } else if(str == "Wheel Click") {
        INDEX = 3;
    } else {
        INDEX = 4;
    }
    }
    pThread_Fist = ::AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc, (LPVOID)INDEX);
}
```

After I made a thread( This thread should run until the end of this program because I want to make this function works just like a mouse.), I thought it'll work perfectly.

However, since I used "while(1)" in ThreadFunc, my program freezed when I selected one option in Combo box. Also I planned this function waits until I unlock my Myo and take a certain pose,

and this function does "left click" once when I take a pose, but it continuously make a Left Click like a forever.

Please give me some advices. 
This is my points.

1. I want to make a MFC program which works just like a mouse.
2. I have a problem in making a thread runs background and does "click" when I want to do. (hope another solutions..)
3. I don't want to change my code dramatically if there are any serious problems in it.
4. Also, I have 5 Combo boxes and All five combo boxes are linked with different click events(Left, Right, Double etc.). I planned to make 5 threads and run them in the same time.

Comment: Since you never reset your index variable, your background thread will run forever and flood the target with an infinite number of mouse messages.

Comment: @WernerHenze I think [Project M](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4938761/project-m) is not familiar with the concept of threads and just wrote some regular code and delegated it into a thread hoping it would solve his problem.

Comment: You seem to be pretty successful in ignoring recommendations. Even though you'll probably ignore this one again, I'll leave it for future visitors, that may not: `1` `mouse_event` is inappropriate, and the documentation does tell you. Use [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) instead. `2` Faking input is almost always wrong. It is here anyway. Use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). That's what it's for.

Comment: `while(1)` is an endless loop. Also I do not understand how this is related to your Myo.

Comment: @WernerHenze I know that while(1) is an endless loop. I thought that since this thread runs in background, it would be no problem, but now i know it is inappropriate.

This is related to myo because I use "myo::Pose::---" in here.

Comment: @mg30rg It is true that I don't know Thread well enough to use as I want. I studied it alone and I am trying to use it.

Comment: @IInspectable I didn't mean to ignore your advice and I am sorry for that.
Before I use SendInput, I just want to use mouse_event because it seems more easier to me and Some people recommended it to me before ask in this site. Although I used mouse_event in this code, I was looking for the SendInput and study it. 
Probably I should have use it earlier :(

Comment: @project What do you think is the sense of your endless loop where pParam never changes?

Comment: @mg30rg Thank you for the answer!  Please give me some time to read it. I just checked here and about to read it!

Comment: @WernerHenze I was about to write code to end thread when I select other option in combo box, (i didn't write it yet).  Anyway I think this is my mistake and misunderstanding about thread and etc. 
I'll fix it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thread function has an infinite loop with no way to terminate constantly sending windows messages which is generally a bad idea.

---

Let's analyze what happens in your code:

Main thread:

```
void CMyoControllerView::OnCbnSelchangeComboFist()
{
    //... determine the action to be taken
    pThread_Fist = ::AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc, (LPVOID)INDEX); // create a new thread on every OnCbnSelchangeComboFist() event.
}
```

Thread core:

```
while(1) 
{
    if(index == 0) 
    {        // Left Click
        // ... send mouse message
    }
    //...
}
```

Now, since you don't change the value of index in your thread, the loop will run infinitely and sends mouse messages infinitely, and when the OnCbnSelchangeComboFist() runs again (if it ever runs again) it will create an other instance of the thread and from then you will have two threads sending mouse messages infinitely.

Comment: Now I understand what was a problem.
I should not use while(1) and then use something else.
(However, I have no idea how can I make this thread to wait until I change Pose. T_T)

Also.. then...do I have to make a thread First and put 

if(nIndex != CB_ERR){ 
    m_combo_Fist.GetLBText(nIndex, str); 

    if(str == "Left Click") {
        INDEX = 0;
      ...
    } else if(str == "Wheel Click") {
        INDEX = 3;
    } else {
        INDEX = 4;

in that thread? (I mean Not exactly same code.. modify and put it)

Comment: You should not do user interaction in your worker thread. What you should do is to create a thread with some means to communicate with the UI thread (it can has its own message loop or it can just listen to an event and read information from a dedicated memory are when it is set), and handle the event/message in your thread.